# Java Breakout game lags

Tags: java

I wrote a Breakout game and i am actually finish. Is my first "big" java project. The game runs smoothly on my Computer, no laggs and no issues. But if i run it on my laptop (the same code) then it runs slowler and it lags. And i am sure the hardware of my laptop is enough to run this. Should i use an other game loop or is it just a problem with my laptop? Both of them have Windows 10.

I did a test on an other laptop (Win 7) and their it runs without lags, and on a third Laptop(Win 10) but their the same problem.

Ok, I found something. When i start the intel graphic control panel and then the game it runs perfectly. When i run it without starting the intel graphic control panel it lags.

Hope you can help me.

This is my gameplay class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Gameplay extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{



 private Timer timer;
 private int  delay = 5;


 //Timer tm= new Timer(5, this);

 boolean play = false;
 int score = 0;

 int totalBricks = 28;



 // Paddle
 int xbat = 355 , velX = 0;

 //Image img;


 //Ball

 int xball = 395,  yball = 450;
 int ballXdir = 5;
 int ballYdir = -3;


 Font f1 = new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20);


 public BrickMap map;

 public Gameplay()
 {

    map = new BrickMap(4,7);
    //tm.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    timer = new Timer(delay,this);
    timer.start();

 }







  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {

    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect(0,0,800,700);

        // Paddle
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(xbat, 600, 110, 17);

    // Ball
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillOval(xball, yball, 22,22);


    //Won
    if(totalBricks <= 0){
        play = false;
        ballXdir = 0;
        ballYdir = 0;
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.setFont(f1);
        g.drawString("You Won " + score,320 ,350);

        g.setFont(f1);
        g.drawString("Mit Enter neustarten",350 ,660);

    }
    // Game Over
    if(yball > 605){
        play = false;
        ballXdir = 0;
        ballYdir = 0;
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.setFont(f1);
        g.drawString("Game Over, Score: " + score,320 ,400);

        g.setFont(f1);
        g.drawString("Mit Enter neustarten",350 ,660);
    }


    // score
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.setFont(f1);
    g.drawString(""+score,5 ,660);

    // Bricks
    map.draw((Graphics2D)g);



       g.dispose();


 }



 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
    timer.start();


 // Paddle----------------------------
    if (xbat < 0) {
        velX =0;
        xbat = 0;
    }

    if (xbat > 690) {
        velX = 0;
        xbat = 690;
    }

    xbat = xbat + velX;
 //----------------------------------

 // Ball-----------------------------

    //Paddle und ball detection
    if(play) {
        if(new Rectangle(xball, yball, 22, 22).intersects(new Rectangle(xbat, 600, 110, 17))) {

           ballXdir = (int) (Math.random()*5);

           if(ballXdir <3){

           }
           else{
               ballXdir = -ballXdir;
           }

           ballYdir = -ballYdir;


        }


        //ball und bricks
       A: for(int i = 0; i < map.map.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < map.map[0].length; j++){
                if(map.map[i][j] > 0){
                    int brickX = j * map.brickWigth + 80;
                    int brickY = i * map.brickHeight + 50;
                    int brickWidth = map.brickWigth;
                    int brickHeight = map.brickHeight;


                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(brickX, brickY, brickWidth, brickHeight);
                    Rectangle ballRect = new Rectangle(xball, yball, 22, 22);
                    Rectangle brickRect = rect;


                    // Der Ball trifft auf die Bricks. Ein Brick wird      abgezogen und 10 Punkte zur Score hinzugefügt
                    if(ballRect.intersects(brickRect)){
                        map.setBrickValue(0 , i , j);
                        totalBricks --;
                        score += 10;


                        if(xball + 22 <= brickRect.x || xball + 1 >=   brickRect.x + brickRect.width){
                            ballXdir = -ballXdir;

                        } else {
                            ballYdir = -ballYdir;
                        }

                        break A;
                    }

                }
            }
        }


        xball += ballXdir;
        yball += ballYdir;
        if(xball < 0){
            ballXdir = -ballXdir;
        }
        if(yball < 0){
            ballYdir = -ballYdir;
        }
        if(xball > 778){
            ballXdir = -ballXdir;
        }



    }

 //----------------------------------


    repaint();


 }




 @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
   //Paddle------------------------------------------
        int c = e.getKeyCode();

        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            play = true;

            velX = +6;
        }

        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            play = true;

            velX = -6;
        }
   //-----------------------------------------------

        //Wenn Enter gedrückt wird
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
            if(!play){
                play = true;
                xball = 395;
                yball = 450;
                ballXdir = 5;
                ballYdir = -3;
                xbat = 355;
                score = 0;
                totalBricks = 28;
                map = new BrickMap(4, 7);


            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
  //Paddle--------------------------------------
    velX= 0;
  //--------------------------------------------
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }




 }
```

Comment: This question probably belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Some wild guesses: This happens because of stress on the garbage collector.

You create many objects that only live for a short time, e.g.  in `paint()`:   `g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 25));`. You create a fresh `Font`  instance per `paint` event.

Without looking it up, I would guess that  `Font` is a very "big" object, thus putting a lot of pressure on memory management.

Try to put the font into a global variable:

```
public class gameplay extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
// ...
public final SCORE_FONT = new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 25);
// ...

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
   // ...
   g.setFont(SCORE_FONT);
   // ...
  }
}
```

BTW: Java conventions write class names in CamelCase, e.g. `public class Gameplay`.